# Insert text into table with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to insert text into a html table using lxml.

The table is simple, it has a single header. And I want to parse a list of items, and each of these items should have a row in the table. As such:

```
--------
| HEAD |
--------
| Item |
--------
| Item |
--------
```

I have created a function that takes a path and a template. The path is for saving the page, and the template is a .html that it uses to insert the data. My code looks like this:

```
def genereate_page(path, template):
    tree = html.parse(template)
    root = tree.getroot()

    items = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']

    table = root.findall('.//*[@table="results"]')

    for i in items:
        row = etree.Element('tr')
        data = etree.Element('td')
        data.text = i
        row.append(data)
        table.append(row)

    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

My template file looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="results">
      <tr id="header_row">
        <th>Test</th>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything compiles, and no error is given, but no text is ever inserted. I just get the template returned, it does however close the header_row, so something is happening. How do I go about inserting text from a list of items into a table using lxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `table` variable is a list and `table.append()` simply add item to the list. Since there is only one table in the HTML, you can use `find()` instead of `findall()` to get the *table element*, and then correctly append a child element to it :

```
table = root.find('.//*[@id="results"]')

for i in items:
    row = etree.Element('tr')
    data = etree.Element('td')
    data.text = i
    row.append(data)
    table.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Is there a reason why you use [@id="results"] instead of [@table="results"] to find the table?

Comment: @cenh Because, in your HTML template, 'results' is the value of `id` attribute, not `table` attribute (there even no such attribute named table in the template). Notice that `@attribute_name` is the way you reference an HTML attribute in XPath.